# Minimum number of edges needed to convert a forest into a tree

Tags: graph-algorithm

What is the minimum number of edges needed to convert a forest into a tree. Forest is given by an adjacency matrix. e.g. given this adjacency matrix (representing the forest) ,

```
0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 1 0 0   
0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 0 1   
0 0 0 0 0
```

what is the minimum no of edges needed to convert it to a graph. Well the answer is 1, but how to do it through a program ?

Comment: A forest is a graph already. Do you mean to turn it into a tree? If so, then check for cycles. If there is any: Impossible, else for tree it holds that you have one edge less than you have vertices, so that is that you want to reach. So #[Vertices] - 1 - [edges you already have]

Comment: Yes I forest is a kind of graph only, sorry to be ambiguous.

Comment: But in a forest , we can not visit every vertex starting from anyone vertex,   so I want to convert this forest into a kind of graph so that starting from one vertex we can visit every other vertex by adding one or more edges.

Comment: You are confusing "graphs" with "trees". Want to do is to make your forest having the property of being "connected". In this case my answer above holds.

Comment: you mean a connected graph. the number of edges needed to connect all the trees is number of trees - 1.

Comment: yes , what I want is a connected graph.   I want the number of edges needed to make the forest a connected graph

Comment: yup thanks...but i am struggling with writing a program for this. I have the above Adjacency matrix as Input. and I have to find out the number of edges needed to make it connected.

Comment: i am trying to get the algorithm for this..

Comment: If you really want to convert a forest into a tree, the answer for the given example is 1 (not 2). C.f. comment by @1010. Please lookup definitions for tree, directed graph, connected components, and strongly connected components (e.g. Wikipedia) and try to formulate your question more accurately.

Comment: @stephan node 0 is a one node tree (the third tree).

Comment: @1010 of course, I missed that one. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to take a graph (which is potentially a forest of disconnected graphs) and find the minimum number of edges that will connect it? Fairly simple, I would say:

1. Find the connected components of the graph.
2. Return the count of the components minus 1.

The reasoning here is that for C components, you only need to (C - 1) edges to connect them up into a tree, which will connect the graph.

Comment: That is the optimal solution. You can use DFS or BFS to find connected components in any graph.